# How many endings does Danganronpa have?

Tags: danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc

I wanted to know how many endings does Danganronpa have.

Comment: Are you counting game overs as endings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are talking about the main plot (that means, not including the School Mode that you get after beating the game), there are two endings for the first Danganronpa episode: a good one and a bad one. The bad one will ultimately lead you to the point where you can choose between the good and the bad ending.

If you really want to know when this division happens, check the following part:

for the trigger part:

> In chapter 5, there is a part when you have a choice to make: either reveal some information about Kyoko Kirigiri which will lead the students to vote against her, or hide it, which will lead the students to vote against you.

for the bad ending:

> If you decide to reveal the information about Kirigiri, you will go for the bad ending: Kirigiri is killed by Monokuna. It is then said that this trial has been the ultimate one, as no one else was murdered in the Academy after that point. We then see a picture of the four remaining students, who are way older: Makoto Naegi, Byakuya Togami (holding a frame with a photo of Toko Fukawa, probably dead for some reasons), Yasuhiro Hagakure and Aoi Asahina (holding two babies, one looking like Naegi and the other looking like Yasuhiro. There is by the way another kid, looking like Togami). This ending will lead you back to the point when you had to decide if you wanted to reveal the information about Kirigiri or not.

and for the good one:

> If you decide to lie to the rest of the students, you will then go for the true (and canon) ending, the 6th chapter, where you finally learn who Monokuna is and you succeed in escaping the Academy.

Answer (score -6):

I wasn't sure which game you meant, however each game has endings in basically the same way: 1 good ending, with a bad ending that sends you back to a check point